# Can't reshow hidden dropdown

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble getting reference to my dropdown after it's been hidden prior.

So based on some action I'm doing a hide() on my dropdown which works fine. But later if some other action happens where I want to show the dropdown gain, I'm getting a null ref on the dropdown pointer:

at some point I hide this dropdown based on a user action:

```
var ddlElotizType= "#" + document.getElementById('<%=ddlElotizType.ClientID %>');

$('#' + ddlElotizType.id).hide();
```

then later based on another action I try to show it again in order to do a show() on it:

```
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('<%=ddlElotizType.ClientID %>');
    $('#' + dropdown.id).show();
    $('#' + dropdown.id).attr("disabled", false);

...
    <fieldset>
        <p class="formLabel"><%="Car Type" %></p>
        <p class="formField"><label id="singleCarTypeText" /><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlElotizType" runat="server" /></p>
    </fieldset>
```

I get a js error saying "dropdown is null" when I try to reference it by id again;

it seems like I can reference the dropdown by element id above only if it's visible already but I would think it shouldn't matter if it is hidden, it's still in the DOM tree right? still accessible...it's gotta be.

Comment: You should provide relevant parts of your code (hiding part, HTML markup)

Comment: Do you hide ddlElotizType dropdown with setting Visible="false" on it?

Comment: If the dropdown is made hidden in server side by "Visible = false" the dom wont contain the select element.

Comment: no haven't used visible = false, just show() or hide()

Comment: Could you show more markup and server-side code? Do you use UpdatePanel controls?

Comment: Hell no, I wouldn't consider touching update panels.  Pardon my comment but that crap from MS is trash.  You don't need that when you have plain mark-up and jquery (js)...this MS trash is unecessary overhead and necessary blackbox magic crap.

Comment: resolved.  I had a tag formed as <label ... /> instead of <label ...></label> that was getting in the way.

Comment: or it was this that worked $(dropdown).show();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because a disabled method is not reachable. You just need to hide it with `.hide()`, not also disable it. Also you're mixing standard DOM methods and jQuery. jQuery already performs the search for you. Here is how you can show the element.

```
var dropdownId = '<%=ddlElotizType.ClientID %>';
$('#' + dropdownId).show();
```

When you hide your element, don't also disable it.

Comment: ya haven't cleaned it up to use jQuery on some of the document.getElementById...I'll do that later.

Comment: I want the dropdown to show up but be disabled because the dropdown won't have initial values until a user selects a previous dropdown before it which will then populate this dropdown and enable it once I dynamically push items to the dropdown list.  So I want to re-show it..that's my first issue and can't due to the null ref.

Comment: Experiment trying with the fully visible dropdown first, then only hidden, then only disabled, and see where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using double `"#"` . Please avoid that.

```
var ddlElotizType= "#" + document.getElementById('<%=ddlElotizType.ClientID %>');
```

**Correct Method:**

**EDIT:**

Variable to Store ID:

```
var ddlElotizTypeID='<%=ddlElotizType.ClientID %>';
```

Hide like this

```
$('#'+ddlElotizTypeID).hide();
```

Show the DropDownList like this.

```
$('#'+ddlElotizTypeID).show();
```

This will work.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing you are, but shoving it into a variable first for cleaner reference...I have done this before so I know my code works.  I like to append the # into a variable so I can just use the variable and not have sloppy repeated long text such as the #<%=someControl.ClientID %> all over my code...I can just put that in a var and reuse the var in the designated scope

Comment: then use a simple JavaScript variable (fast), don't do an useless DOM search (slow). updated my answer.

Comment: yea I haven't cleaned up and removed all the document.getElementById...I'll do that at the end of this feature I'm building out...had some older code in it

Comment: yea I'm doing that now, like I said I did not clean my code up yet

Comment: I like this better var someVar = $("#<%=ddlElotizType.ClientID %>")